# SQL - How to ReOrganise a set of Rows

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, rows

I have a table with the columns Name, QueuePosition

```
Name  QueuePosition
John      1
Paul      1
Mike      2
Sarah     3
Kevin     4
George    4
```

How do i reorder them quickly to be like this?

```
Name  QueuePosition
John      1
Paul      2
Mike      3
Sarah     4
Kevin     5
George    6
```

Thanks

Edit -Should have been more specific

i need it to be permanent if possible. Not just a select statement.

There will be no more than 10 names in list. Possibly have to just save them in an array and overwrite the whole list. I was wondering is there a quick way of doing this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: If I understood well, you could insert all those names in a new table, and define the QueuePosition as an AUTOINCREMENT.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, SQL tables represent unordered sets.  So, there is no way to ensure that "John" comes before "Paul", unless you have another column.

The canonical approach to what you want is the `row_number()` function.  This is an ANSI standard function supported by most databases.  The query is:

```
select name, row_number() over (order by QueuePosition) as QueuePosition
from table t;
```

This can also be folded into an `update`, but the syntax would vary by database.

EDIT:

In SQLite you can do:

```
with toupdate as (
      select name, row_number() over (order by QueuePosition) as QueuePosition
      from tablename
     )
update tablename
    set QueuePosition = (select QueuePosition from toupdate where toupdate.name = tablename.name);
```

EDIT II;

In SQLite you can do:

```
with toupdate as (
      select name, (select count(*) from tablename t2 where t2.QueuePosition <= t.QueuePosition) as QueuePosition
      from tablename t
     )
update tablename
    set QueuePosition = (select QueuePosition from toupdate where toupdate.name = tablename.name);
```

Comment: SQLite does not have window functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
update yourTableName set QueuePosition = ROWID
```

Comment: Previously deleted rows might result in gaps in the sequence.